# Convert int array to string separated by ','

Tags: go

I know that for string array `[]string` I can use `strings.Join(a []string, ',')` but I want to do the same thing for an integer array `[]int`.

My usecase is something like this for a query where `variants` is `[]map[string]int`

```
 var Ids []int
    sqlStr := "select id from mapping where my_id in ("
    for _, mp := range variants {
       sqlStr += "?,"
       Ids = append(Ids, mp["id"])
    }
    sqlStr = strings.TrimRight(sqlStr, ",")
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlStr+")", strings.Join(Ids, ',')) // I can't do this because Join needs String array
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this question. Atleast tell me what is the mistake and help me improve.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make `IDs` a `[]string` and convert the integers when you append them

```
var IDs []string
for _, i := range []int{1, 2, 3, 4} {
    IDs = append(IDs, strconv.Itoa(i))
}

fmt.Println(strings.Join(IDs, ", "))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xrfuMRjgiI

Answer (score 9):

I would prefer to use `json.Marshal`. It is much simple and easy to use.

```
data := []int{100, 200, 300}
s, _ := json.Marshal(data)

fmt.Println(strings.Trim(string(s), "[]"))
```

[GoPlaygroundLink](https://play.golang.org/p/k9w-dkxNNhI)

I hope this helps you. Please feel free to ask in case of doubts. [WebsiteLink](http://www.cstechera.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient way to do that:

```
func sqlIntSeq(ns []int) string {
    if len(ns) == 0 {
        return ""
    }

    // Appr. 3 chars per num plus the comma.
    estimate := len(ns) * 4
    b := make([]byte, 0, estimate)
    // Or simply
    //   b := []byte{}
    for _, n := range ns {
        b = strconv.AppendInt(b, int64(n), 10)
        b = append(b, ',')
    }
    b = b[:len(b)-1]
    return string(b)
}
```

You can use it in the SQL queries like that:

```
query := `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (` + sqlIntSeq(ids) + `)`
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/zi7YYetGu7.

Comment: Ah `AppendInt` is a little nicer. Small nit, I would stick to the official style recommendation of starting with an a nil/empty slice. It makes beginner examples like this easier to understand, and I highly doubt that _one_ extra stack alloc&copy is going to make a difference during this string manipulation ;)